# Issues with cloudinary dependencies in Java

Tags: java, jsp, cloudinary

im trying to connect a java ee application to cloudinary to upload and display images using a java backend. However after importing the cloudinary files as external jars and importing the files in the java file I was met with a status 500 error 'Unable to compile class for JSP:' which I think may be an issue with the dependencies

I was expecting to get the image URL printed onto the jsp page that I connected to my Java file but I just got an error

The Java file

```
package cloudinary;

import com.cloudinary.Cloudinary;
import com.cloudinary.utils.ObjectUtils;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Map;

public class cloudinary_test {
    private static final String CLOUD_NAME = "my_cloud_name";
    private static final String API_KEY = "my_api_key";
    private static final String API_SECRET = "my_api_secret";

    public static String uploadImage(HttpServletRequest request) {
        String imageURL = null;

        // Configure Cloudinary
        Cloudinary cloudinary = new Cloudinary(ObjectUtils.asMap(
                "cloud_name", CLOUD_NAME,
                "api_key", API_KEY,
                "api_secret", API_SECRET
        ));

        try {
            // Uploading a file path to Cloudinary
            File imageFile = new File(request.getServletContext().getRealPath("/img/book_logo.jpg"));
            Map uploadResult = cloudinary.uploader().upload(imageFile, ObjectUtils.asMap("folder", "JAD_CA1"));

            // Retrieve the URL of the uploaded image
            imageURL = uploadResult.get("url").toString();
            System.out.println("Image URL: " + imageURL);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return imageURL;
    }
}
```

The test.jsp File

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@ page import="java.util.List"%>
<%@ page import="classes.BookClass"%>
<%@ include file = "HomepageConnection.jsp" %>

<%@ page import="com.cloudinary.*" %>
<%@ page import="com.cloudinary.utils.ObjectUtils" %>
<%@ page import = "cloudinary.cloudinary_test" %>

<%
    String imageURL = cloudinary_test.uploadImage(request);
%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>work pls</h1>

    <div>
        <h2><%= imageURL %></h2>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

The error message when the JSP file is run

`Type Exception Report Message Unable to compile class for JSP: Description The server encountered an unexpected condition that prevented it from fulfilling the request. Exception org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Unable to compile class for JSP: An error occurred at line: [26] in the generated java file: [C:\Users\thadd\eclipse-workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\work\Catalina\localhost\JAD-CA1\org\apache\jsp\test_jsp.java] Only a type can be imported. com.cloudinary.utils.ObjectUtils resolves to a package`

Comment: Please share your error message as the plain text format not image

Comment: Hi sorry heres there error message,

Type Exception Report

Message Unable to compile class for JSP:

Description The server encountered an unexpected condition that prevented it from fulfilling the request.

Exception

org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Unable to compile class for JSP: 

An error occurred at line: [26] in the generated java file: [C:\Users\thadd\eclipse-workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\work\Catalina\localhost\JAD-CA1\org\apache\jsp\test_jsp.java]
Only a type can be imported. com.cloudinary.utils.ObjectUtils resolves to a package

Comment: please update your question with the error message in the plain text format

Answer (score 0):

Hi there please check if `<%@ page import="com.cloudinary.utils.ObjectUtils" %>` has a typo. Also, check if adding ";" at the end solves it:

```
<%@ page import="com.cloudinary.*" %>
<%@ page import = "cloudinary.cloudinary_test" %>
<%@ page import="com.cloudinary.utils.ObjectUtils;" %>
```

Once you're done - stop the server and rebuild the project.